# problem with reading program arguments in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm running C++ program in VS2005, and I've set only one argument in project properties-> debug-> command line args, and it's named `profile1.dll` for example.

here's a code snippet

```
cout<<"number of arguments:" << argc<<endl;

for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
       cout << "argument " << i << ": " << argv[i] << endl;
```

In the output I get

```
number of arguments:2
argument 0: c
argument 1: p
```

don't know why it doesn't print the name of the argument?

Comment: My guess is your main method has argv has type char* rather than char**.  Can't know for sure without seeing your main method decl.

Comment: I think Bob's answer is THE one. You are using UNICODE and 0 is preventing you from printing the whole string. Use UNICODE's functions to print the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the name of your exe start with C? If you expect a string and you only get one character, it's usually because you've discovered that the Western alphabet in UTF-16 Unicode effectively puts a 0 between alternating ANSI chars. Are you compiling for Unicode ?

Comment: I'm using Unicode.
I changed it to multi-byte, but still the same output

Comment: @Kobac: When using Unicode, you should use std::wcout instead of std::cout.

Answer (score 3):

`argv[0]` is the name of your program. `argv[1]` is the first parameter. It sounds like you have declared the relevant parameter in main() as `char* argv` rather than `char *argv[]` or `char **argv`.

Comment: But the OP already said in response to Pablo's answer that he had declared it as char* argv[]. Something's not right here.

Comment: @kobac: thanks for accepting my answer, but as pointed out it wasn't the cause of your problem. Can you accept @Bob Moore's answer instead?

Answer (score 1):

Leave TCHAR be, it's fine.

If you compile with unicode, use wcout for output:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

  for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
    wcout << "argument " << i << ": " << argv[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise compile without unicode and your code will just work as-is (and will not work with unicode parameters :o)

You can find setting in "Project Properties/General/Character Set"

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the prototype of your `main` function? What you are doing is apparently fine.

Make sure your main's function prototype is something similar to:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])//_TCHAR*`
so by default it was _TCHAR* for the argv[], but if so, it print's an integer, so i changed it to char*

Comment: @Kobac: change it back to TCHAR, and use std::wcout instead of std::cout

Comment: Now I see what's happening. You are using UNICODE and 0 are preventing you from printing the whole String. Check Bob's answer out.